# Interrupted system call (os error 4) when consume stream in rust

Tags: rust, redis

I want to consume the stream message from redis in rust, this is how I do it:

```
use redis::{Commands, PubSubCommands, ControlFlow};

fn main() {
    let redis_client = redis::Client::open("redis://default:123456@123456l:6379/1").expect("get redis client failed");
    let mut con = redis_client
        .get_connection()
        .expect("get redis connection failed");
    let mut count = 0;
    let consume_result = con.subscribe(&["texhub-server:proj:s-comp-queue"], |msg| {
        println!("{:?}", msg);
        count += 1;
        match count {
            10 => ControlFlow::Break(()),
            _ => ControlFlow::Continue,
        }
    });
    if let Err(err) = consume_result {
        println!("{}", err);
    }
}
```

but the process just throw `Interrupted system call (os error 4)` error. Am I missing something? what should I do to fixed this issue? I am sure the stream with name `texhub-server:proj:s-comp-queue` exists in redis and the list is not empty. This is the project `Cargo.toml`:

```
[package]
name = "rust-learn"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
rust_wheel = { git = "https://github.com/jiangxiaoqiang/rust_wheel.git", branch = "diesel2.0", features = ["model","common","rwconfig"]}
redis = "0.21.3"
```

BTW, this is how I put the stream:

```
pub fn push_to_stream(
    stream_key: &str,
    params: &[(&str, &str)],
)  {
    let redis_client = redis::Client::open("redis://default:123456@123456l:6379/1").expect("get redis client failed");
    let mut con = redis_client
        .get_connection()
        .expect("get redis connection failed");
    let result = con.xadd::<&str, &str, &str, &str, String>(stream_key, "*", params);
    if let Err(err) = result {
        println!("{}", err);
    }
}
```

I have tried to upgrade the redis to 0.23.3 and tweak my code follow the official like this:

```
use redis::{Commands, PubSubCommands, ControlFlow, RedisError};

fn main() {
    let redis_client = redis::Client::open("redis://default:123456@123456l:6379/1").expect("get redis client failed");
    let mut con = redis_client
        .get_connection()
        .expect("get redis connection failed");
    let mut pubsub = con.as_pubsub();
    let sub_result = pubsub.subscribe("texhub.compile_stream_redis_key");
    if let Err(sub_err) = sub_result {
        println!("subscribe error {}", sub_err);
    }
    loop {
        let msg = pubsub.get_message();
        if let Err(e) = msg {
            println!("subscribe message error {}", e);
            return;
        }
        let payload: Result<String, RedisError> = msg.as_ref().unwrap().get_payload();
        if let Err(e) = payload {
            println!("payload message error {}", e);
            return;
        }
        println!(
            "channel '{}': {}",
            msg.unwrap().get_channel_name(),
            payload.unwrap()
        );
    }
}
```

still the same issue.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, it's more a nit pick. But if all you need is a `&str` to connect to redis database, then you don't have to allocate an owned `String`. In rust string literals already have type `&'static str`. And if you insist on creating `String` you can pass a reference to it to a function accepting a `&str`, and rust will perform automatic dereferention for you.

Comment: I have optimized my code.